# What is the difference between "before the law" and "under the law"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference, prepositional-phrases

Both usages are listed on [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/law?q=law), but is there any difference?

> **Under existing law**, journalists cannot refuse to provide information to a jury.

> The constitution guarantees equality **before the law** for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Under the (existing) law*, journalists cannot refuse to provide information to a jury**. This means that the existing law does not allow such an action. This is a common expression because law changes widely over time and places. So you may get a statement such as: "Abortion is a crime under the law of country A, but not under the law of country B."

**The constitution guarantees equality *before the law* for all**. This expression is often used to describe the principle that law should be applied impartially. Everyone should be treated equally in legal matters regardless of gender, race, wealth and so on.

If we wrote a paragraph to show the relationship between those two phrases, it might look like this:

> Under the existing law, journalists cannot refuse to provide information to a jury. But journalist A did refuse, and the judge did not reprimand him. The rumours are that this happened because judge and journalist are close friends. So the defendant didn't get a fair trial, and wasn't treated with justice before the law.

Comment: Thank you. My initial intuition was about the same as what you said, but here is a thing that looks like a counterexample. On a Wikipedia page of "Equality before the law", it's said to be "also know as equality under the law". So it's kind of implying the two words mean the same thing. What do you think about this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_before_the_law

Comment: Yes, there does seem to be an overlap in meaning. It's not an overlap that I've seen before, but I'm willing to accept Wiki's evidence that there are different uses. (It's worth noting that the overlap is one sided. Using your original example, we couldn't say, "Before the law, journalists can't refuse...")

Comment: "It's worth noting that the overlap is one sided." Thanks, that's a good point. Even if it's a counterexample, they don't seem like always interchangeable. But I think it's possible that the article is not a legit counterexample, because I don't know how the word is "also know as". I haven't very deeply dived into it, but I couldn't find any source there that supports the word is "also know as equality under the law". The all examples shown on the page use "before", not "under", as far as I can see.